# generating webstats from heroku logs

Tags: heroku, google-analytics

In the olden days when I made a website I'd install a webstat counter program that analysed the apache logs and told me who was visiting from where etc.

I'd like something like that but for heroku.

I don't want to use google analytics or anything client side, it needs to run server side.

Does something like that exist?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, exists! You can use the Google Analytics measurement protocol to communicate on the server and implement google analytics in your application.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/

There are also other tools that work similarly to Google analytics, but if you prefer the Google interface, it is possible to perform a server side implementation.